# Are RC folders obsolete on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, init, runlevel

I am learning Linux, using Ubuntu. I wanted to remove network management from one of the run levels. I had done this correctly before, but now, no matter how hard I try, I can not remove a script from the desired run levels.

[image]

the rc3 folder is empty so how can I work on run level 3?!

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with version 15.04 Ubuntu switched to [systemd](https://systemd.io/). The rcX.d folders are mostly obsolete.

You can use a configuration command like `sudo systemctl disable network-manager.service` to disable the network manager (which should leave the networking mostly unconfigured).

There are no runlevels in systemd, but an equivalent called "targets". [tecmint](https://www.tecmint.com/change-runlevels-targets-in-systemd/) lists the mapping like this:

> - Run level 0 is matched by poweroff.target.
> - Run level 1 is matched by rescue.target.
> - Run level 3 is emulated by multi-user.target.
> - Run level 5 is emulated by graphical.target.
> - Run level 6 is emulated by reboot.target.

You can switch to a specific target via `systemctl isolate multi-user.target`. Symlinks usually exist, so you can also enter `systemctl isolate runlevel3.target`

In order to remove a unit from a particular target, you can modifiy the unit's `WantedBy` directive. Please be aware that targets can depend on each other, so removing a unit from a target will also remove it from the dependees.

Comment: I'm familiar with systemctl, but I mean something else
I'm looking for permanent change for runlevels.

Comment: I extended my answer.